# Why would my keyboard respond extremely slowly when dealing with multiple nested layouts on a *specific device?

Tags: android, performance, keyboard, viewflipper

I have an app that has a very lengthy registration form filled with all sorts of Spinners and checkboxes and you-name-its.  I'm presenting them all (for clarity) in a ViewFlipper and offering them to the user one at a time.

On all the handset devices that I'm testing this on, it works perfectly.  However, when running on a Samsung Galaxy Node 2 (the latest one), the keyboard grinds to an unusable glacial pace, with keys taking multiple seconds to respond.  This appears to be directly connected to the spinners that are NOT displayed but are part of the layout (because when I remove those particular Layouts from the Flipper everything speeds up dramatically, though still not back to what you'd expect from a late generation Android tablet).

Is there something I should know about app performance when dealing with a ViewFlipper that has many child layouts?  The layouts themselves are pretty simple... just a few Views each, except for the Spinners, some of which have tens of AdapterViews as selectable items.

I realize this question is somewhat vague, but I don't really know what to do, other than to refactor my code to load the Flipper's children 1 at a time and dismiss them when they're out of sight, which is a colossal hassle that I'm hoping to avoid, especially given that it works brilliantly on all the *other devices I've tested this on.

I turned on harware accel in the manifest as a last ditch attempt, but, as expected that didn't do anything helpful.